# Swift - Accessing AppDelegate window from viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I make walkthrough (onboarding flow) in my app and I'd like to have a skip button.
The button is located on viewController, so I figured out that the best way to move to another viewController would be access app delegate window.

However, it keeps getting me an error that AppDelegate.Type does not have a member called "window".

```
@IBAction func skipWalkthrough(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    AppDelegate.window!.rootViewController = RootViewController   
}
```

Is there anything wrong with such approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also try to get visible viewcontroller

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have a typo it is supposed to be `appDelegate` not `AppDelegate`. So like this:

```
@IBAction func skipWalkthrough(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = RootViewController   
}
```

**Swift 3.2**

```
@IBAction func skipWalkthrough(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = controller
    }
```

Comment: Ok right, what a studip mistake! Btw, now there is a problem with RootViewController, how to access this view controller which is declared in storyboard? I guess making a new instance isn't a good idea? I mean RootViewController() leads to black screen, so should be another wait to access such controller

Comment: Here is how I do it in my code `let storyboardId = "LoginStoryboardIdentifier"`
       `self.window?.rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardId) as? UIViewController`

Comment: Works perfectly but while noticing memory consumption, I see no memory decrease when I replace the Root View controller (a) with (b).
It means (a) has not wiped out from the memory, right?
How to wipe it out from memory 1st and then show (b) controller

Answer (score 20):

This is for with or without Storyboard and it is working for **Swift 3+**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = homeController
```

Comment: Does this still work in Swift 5+, I can't seem to get this to work, the line appDelegate?.window throws an error saying cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'any', fixing it gives other errors.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3

This is a better way:

```
    if let window = NSApplication.shared().windows.first {
        window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true;
    }
```

Comment: NSApplication is use in MacOS this question is tag in iOS

Answer (score 10):

`appDelegate.window!.rootViewController` is not working in **Swift 5**

**Here is working code**

**Add below extension**

```
extension UIWindow {
    static var key: UIWindow! {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}
```

**use**

```
let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    
if let RootVc = mainSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as? UINavigationController{
    UIWindow.key.rootViewController = RootVc
}

UIWindow.key // to access only window
```

Comment: This is how you access instance of UIWindow in Swift5 , iOS 13 & above versions to set it's rootViewController or to present any UIView. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Suhail I forgot 1 line to Add **window.makeKeyAndVisible()** Please check my Updated Answer it will sure work :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use conditional binding to reach the `window`.

```swift
if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
    // use window here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the protocol name (i.e. `AppDelegate`) instead of the instance:

Should be:

```
appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = RootViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access tab bar anywhere from the app. Use below:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

if let tabBarController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    if let tabItems = tabBarController.tabBar.items {
       let tabItem = tabItems[2]
       tabItem.badgeValue = "5" //enter any value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for :
 After Login / Register Programmatically add `UITabbarController`

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = tabs
appDelegate.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.